# Focusing a picture with locked background

Tags: jquery, html, css

On Facebook you see a picture and the rest of the screen turns locked grey, 
and until you close that picture you can't do anything else. What's the logic behind it? 
Is it an object I need to put hidden as part of my CSS? 
Is it a code line built in with jQuery? 
What is the proper and acceptable method to treat this thing?

I know it's jQuery, but can't wrap my head around the idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check the [thickbox](http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/) or [lightbox plugin for jQuery](http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/) and [other lightbox](https://www.google.com/search?q=lightbox) and [thickbox projects](http://www.google.com/search?q=thickbox).

For other modal dialogs (that lay over the page an diasable it) take a look at the [dialog component](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) of the jQuery UI framework.

If you take a look at the demo pages and use your browser's built in development tools, you can see how it works. Thickbox for example has an overlaying div to disable the whole page:

```
<div id="TB_overlay" class="TB_overlayBG"></div>
```

with the following CSS:

```
#TB_overlay {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 100;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

As you can see, the thing has a z-index of 100 to be on top of the rest and is streched over the whole page.

Secondly there is the overlaying window

```
<div id="TB_window" ...></div>
```

centered with an z-index of 102, to be in front of the above mentioned overlay:

```
#TB_window {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 102;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  ...
}
```

Comment: I'm retracting the downvote since the answer is substantially expanded since, but it started out with literally just "You should check lightbox" which did not even answer the question.

Comment: @Juhana: Yeah, you're right. I realized that after the downvote, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean a [lightbox](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/) effect.

It's often done with an overlay div absolutely positionned relative to the body element, width 100% width and height :

```
div.overlay { 
position : absolute; 
top : 0; 
left : 0; 
width : 100%;
height : 100%; 
}
```

Inside this overlay, you put your image, per example :

```
div.overlay img {
position : absolute;
top : 50%;
left : 50%;
margin-left : /* negative half the width of your image */
margin-top: /* negative half the height of your image */
}
```

It's only one of many way to do it (this one works only if you know the dimensions of your image.) Often the centering is computed via javascript.

Search for lightbox, you'll find tons of Jquery plugins and tutorials.